# How can I setup my Redux Initial state as an Object, and then properly sync it with my reducer functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so I am new to react Redux and I was able to set up a reducer that fetches a number from the backend and allows me to increment or decrement it by a 1000.

On the server side the number comes from the 'routes/api/users' file and shows

```
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors');
const { Router } = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const number = {count:2150, holder:'James'}

router.get('/', async(req,res)=>{
    console.log('a GET request was made', req.body)
        res.send(number)
    })
router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{

console.log('a POST request was made', req.body)
number.count = req.body.count
res.send(number)
})

module.exports = router;
```

So the backend sends number, which is an object with a holder name and count.==> {count:2150, holder:James}

the React front end then picks up the count via this reducer function

```
/// FETCH DATA
export const GetData = () =>{

return async (dispatch, getState) =>{
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:9700/api/users')
     console.log('it worked ', response.data.count)
     dispatch({
            type:"FETCH_DATA",
            payload: response.data.count})
            }}
```

This is the reducer code

```
const reducer = (state = number, action )=>{
switch(action.type){

case "FETCH_DATA":
  return action.payload
  case "deposit":
 return state + action.payload;
case "withdraw":
    return state - action.payload;
  case "POST_DATA":
    state = action.payload
  return action.payload;  
default:
  return state;
}}
```

And this is the rest of the code

```
import axios from "axios"
//// ADD MONEY TO ACCOUNT
export const depositMoney = (amount) =>{
return (dispatch) =>{
dispatch ({
      type:"deposit",
      payload:amount})
}}
//// WITH DRAW MONEY FROM ACCOUNT
export const withDrawMoney=(amount)=>{
return (dispatch)=>{
dispatch({

    type:"withdraw",
    payload:amount    })
}} 
/// FETCH DATA
export const GetData = () =>{

return async (dispatch, getState) =>{
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:9700/api/users')
     console.log('it worked ', response.data.count)
     dispatch({
            type:"FETCH_DATA",
            payload: response.data.count})
            }}

// POST DATA 
export const PostData = (num) =>{
return async  (dispatch, getState) =>{

        const newUser ={
            id:num,
            name:"Heynow"
        }
  const config = {
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
         } }
         const body = JSON.stringify(newUser)
    const response= await axios.post('http://localhost:9700/api/users', body, config)   
    console.log('it worked ', response.data.count)
    dispatch({
            type:"POST_DATA",
            payload: response.data.count })
        }};
```

This is the App.js code

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actionCreators } from './State/index';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import {  PostData, Dummy, GetData } from './State/actions-creators';

function App() {
const account = useSelector((state)=>state.account);
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
console.log(account)
 const {depositMoney, withDrawMoney} = bindActionCreators(actionCreators,dispatch)
useEffect(()=>{

dispatch(GetData());
console.log('hey')
},[]);

  return (
    
      <div className="App">
      <h3>{account}</h3>

 <button onClick={()=>depositMoney(1000)}>Add</button>
 <button onClick={()=>withDrawMoney(1000)}>Subtract</button>
 <button onClick={()=>PostData(0)}>Reset</button>

    </div>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

So I have two problems

1-The first is that my post function does not work, the PostData function is suppose to reset the count to 0 and send that to the server and get an update from the server showing its at 0
However, nothing happens when I click the Reset button (which links to the PostData function)

2- I have tried changing the state from a number to an object with both a holder name and a count like how it is in the backside. However I keep getting an error stating

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {count, holder}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

so can someone please show me how to set up the initialState as an object without causing an error in the overall function?

this is what I tried that got me an error

```
const reducer = (state = {name:'',count:''}, action )=>{
  switch(action.type){
  
  case "FETCH_DATA":
    return action.payload
    case "deposit":
   return  {...state, count:state.count + action.payload};
  case "withdraw":
      return {...state, count:state.count - action.payload};
    case "POST_DATA":
      
    return action.payload;  
  default:
    return state;
  }}


export default reducer
```

and this the modified functions file

```
import axios from "axios"
//// ADD MONEY TO ACCOUNT
export const depositMoney = (amount) =>{
return (dispatch) =>{
dispatch ({
      type:"deposit",
      payload:amount})
}}
//// WITH DRAW MONEY FROM ACCOUNT
export const withDrawMoney=(amount)=>{
return (dispatch)=>{
dispatch({

    type:"withdraw",
    payload:amount    })
}} 
/// FETCH DATA
export const GetData = () =>{

return async (dispatch, getState) =>{
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:9700/api/users')
     console.log('it worked ', response.data.count)
     dispatch({
            type:"FETCH_DATA",
            payload: response.data})
            }}

// POST DATA 
export const PostData = (num) =>{
return async  (dispatch, getState) =>{

        const newUser ={
            id:num,
            name:"Heynow"
        }
  const config = {
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
         } }
         const body = JSON.stringify(newUser)
    const response= await axios.post('http://localhost:9700/api/users', body, config)   
    console.log('it worked ', response.data.count)
    dispatch({
            type:"POST_DATA",
            payload: response.data })
        }};
```

So what do I have to do to properly sync the reducer with the initial state of {count:'',holder:''}?

If anyone can help that would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the body you send via POST does not match the request expected by server (`holder` and `count` vs `name` and `id` properties).

Secondly, the error you get is indicating that you try to render (return in case of functional components) a javascript object, which is forbidden. What you can do is destruct the errorous object or just return one of it's properties, eg.

BAD

```
const data = { count: 1, holder: 'John' };

return (
    <h1>{data}</h1>
);
```

GOOD

```
const data = { count: 1, holder: 'John' };

return (
    <>
        <span>{data.count}</span>
        <span>{data.holder}</span>
    </>
);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.